Implications of the statement: "Note that it is very difficult to remove Rosetta 2 once it is installed"
When attempting to install an app built for Intel Macs on an Apple Silicon Mac, I encounter the following message:

Note that it is very difficult to remove Rosetta 2 once it is installed


What does this statement mean from a technical standpoint? Specifically, what changes occur when installing Rosetta 2 on an Apple Silicon Mac, and what technical reasons make these changes difficult to reverse?

It has to be said that there are no real disadvantages or problems as a results of having Rosetta installed; and no real necessity for removing it.

@benwiggy: As a developer I want to be able to ensure that my software installs and runs on computers without Rosetta, that is reason enough for me to wish an official uninstaller for the case that Rosetta was accidentally installed on a test computer.

@MartinR That's fair. I was perhaps thinking from the "user's" perspective. I have seen a bunch of posts from people who seem to think that their Mac is sullied and somehow less performant just because they've accidentally installed Rosetta.

Hopefully not as severe an issue as if you replace Rosetta with "Norton Antivirus" :-) :-(

Rosetta allows to run (64-bit) Intel apps on Apple silicon by translating the x86_64 instructions.
General documentation about Rosetta from Apple can be found in About the Rosetta Translation Environment.
How does Rosetta 2 work? provides some information how it works under the hood.
Rosetta is difficult to remove because there is no official uninstall method, and because the files installed by  Rosetta are protected by SIP (System Integrity Protection) like other macOS system software.
Inofficial instructions how to get rid of Rosetta can be found e.g. here and here, it essentially amounts to

Getting the file list with
% pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto


Booting into recovery mode to disable SIP.

Removing the files.

Enabling SIP again.


Again: These are inofficial instructions, use at your own risk. I haven't tested it.
Remark: It is a pity that Apple does not provide a method to remove (or at least disable) Rosetta. I know of a case where some software was inadvertently distributed as an Intel-only package instead of a Universal Binary. This went unnoticed because Rosetta was installed on the computer where the software was tested.
